# Google Finance Rounding up Penny Stocks

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

How do I get Google Finance to stop Rounding up Penny Stocks?

I import a stock in to google sheets using the google finance option and it takes .0162 and makes it .16

Any Help Please!

Comment: It could be [Rule 612 (Minimum Pricing Increment)](https://www.sec.gov/divisions/marketreg/subpenny612faq.htm) but can you post an example of such a stock?

Comment: I understand that you are using [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) sheet function. Can you please share a Spreadsheet as example?